# How is it possible for getrusage to measure in microseconds?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

I was trying to get a bit of understanding of `getrusage()` but reading the Linux manual now left me in confusion: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html

> [Measuring] CPU time (e.g., getrusage(2))
>          is limited by the resolution of the software clock, a clock
>          maintained by the kernel which measures time in jiffies. [...] on kernels up to and including
>          2.4.x, HZ was 100, giving a jiffy value of 0.01 seconds; starting
>          with 2.6.0, HZ was raised to 1000, giving a jiffy of 0.001 seconds.

So if I understood correctly, this means that `getrusage()` can't measure anything more precisely than 0.001 seconds = 1000 microseconds. But when running some code I got measurements that were still accurate to the microsecond (like 8097 microseconds (not given in the example below)). How is this possible? How does this function work?

EDIT:

Just as an example. (I'm not on my linux computer so I can't run the code. But it was something like that) On another code I got even a measurement of 0.000734 seconds.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream.h>
int main() 
{
    struct rusage usage;
    struct timeval start, end;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);

    start = usage.ru_utime;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {} // just a simple loop to measure something

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    end = usage.ru_time;

    double total_time = double(1000 * 1000 * end.tv_sec + end.tv_usec) - double(1000 * 1000 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_usec);

    std::cout << "start: " << start.tv_sec << " sec and " << start.tv_usec << " microsec" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end: " << end.tv_sec << " sec and " << end.tv_usec << " microsec" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "total time: " << std::to_string(total_time) << " microsec" << std::endl;

}
```

EDIT 2: It is also not clear to me if `getrusage` uses a high-resolution timer. I can't anything specific about that.

Comment: Show an example. [Mcve].

Comment: just a guess, if a jiffy is 2699 milliseconds then 8097 ms is exactly 3 jiffys. Dont confuse digits of the result with significant digits

Comment: did you also read the next paragraph on high-resolution timers?

Comment: Just because you have numbers that aren't rounded doesn't mean they're _accurate_.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 yes I read it, but it isn't clear if getrusage also uses that.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I also had values below 0.001 seconds. Sorry, did not think about mentioning that. But you're right.

Comment: `iostream.h` : ) `usage.ru_time` your example can't be compiled. After fixing errors and doing `volatile int` in the loop and giving it `< 10000000` something to really calculate, I get `136938.000000 microsec`, like resolution is to microsec

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Accuracy vs. precision strikes again!

Comment: @tadman: Exactly!